# How to get an instance by it's name using googleapiclient

Tags: google-api-client

I am using the `googleapiclient.discovery` as client to connect to GCP. Ideally, I would like to retrieve a virtual machine by it's

- zone
- project
- name

I am having a difficult time finding code samples that do this. I am initializing the client like so

```
client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
```

I've exported the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and I am able to successfully connect to GCP. However, I am unable to fetch an instance by it's name. I am looking for a method like

```
instance = client.compute.instances().get("project","zone","instance_name")
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to set up a client with `discovery` like so

```
compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credential)
getinstance = compute.instances().get(project=project_id, zone=region, instance=instance_id).execute()
```